# Add html content with line break inside d3 circle

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is it possible in d3 to Add html content instead of appending text.In the Following code,

```
 circle.append("circle")
                              .attr("cx", 65)
                              .attr("cy", 65)
                              .attr("r", 65)
                              .attr('fill','none')
                              .attr('stroke','#008080')
                              .attr('class','ourmission')
    circle.append('text')
                              .attr('x', 65)
                              .attr('y',65)
                              .attr('dx',65)
                              .text(function(d){
                              return d.Some_Value+"<br/>"+d.Some_OtherValue
                                             })
```

I have appended text,since I need to add line break to my text dynamically based on some condition I need html content to be added instead of text.If am not wrong I think line break is not possible with appending text.

I need to do some thing like this,

```
  .html(function(d){
      return d.Some_Value+"<br/>"+d.Some_OtherValue
               })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [`<foreignObject>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) element.

> The **foreignObject** SVG element allows for inclusion of a foreign XML
>   namespace which has its graphical content drawn by a different user
>   agent. The included foreign graphical content is subject to SVG
>   transformations and compositing.

Look at the demo below:

```js
var svg = d3.select("#root")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 210)
  .attr("height", 210);

svg.append("circle")
  .style("stroke", "gray")
  .style("fill", "white")
  .attr("r", 100)
  .attr("cx", 105)
  .attr("cy", 105)

svg
  .data([{ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' }])
  .append("foreignObject")
  .attr("x", 60)
  .attr("y", 60)
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .html(function(d) {
    return '<div style="border:1px solid">' + d.foo + '</br>' + d.bar + '</div>'
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.11.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```